# How to get command line from a ClickOnce application?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, clickonce

Before publishing I went to Project -> Properties -> Options -> File Associations and added the extension ".hsp". Set an icon and a ProgID ("MyCompany.Document.1" for testing). After I published and installed, my .hsp files had the icon I set, so the file association should be properly set, but when I double clicked one of these files the application run and I expected the name of the file I double clicked to be in the command line. I tried reading the parameter passed to my `Main` function, tried `Environment.CommandLine`, and tried `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`, but the only thing I found was the application path. By the way I'm doing all this check before creating my main form in the `Main` function, just to test. The `args` parameter is empty and the other two only contain my app path.

This is the beginning of my `Main` function:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);
            MessageBox.Show("CommandLine -> " + Environment.CommandLine);
            foreach (string str in args) MessageBox.Show("args -> " + str);
            foreach (string str in Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()) MessageBox.Show("GetCommandLineArgs -> " + str);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you publish an app with ClickOnce and then launch it by double-clicking an associated file, the path to that file actually gets stored here:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData[0]
```

See MSDN's documentation for it here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.hosting.activationarguments.aspx

Plus a tutorial on adding file associations to "Published" projects:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mwade/archive/2008/01/30/how-to-add-file-associations-to-a-clickonce-application.aspx