# Program won't recognize command line arguments

Tags: c#, .net, command-line-arguments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get command line from a ClickOnce application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607632/how-to-get-command-line-from-a-clickonce-application)

I was working on a console application and manually added the `string[] args` inside of Main() after I had already done a bunch of other work.  Is that all I have to do to accept command line arguments?  Or do I need to configure something elsewhere also?  I keep doing `Console.WriteLine("{0}",args.Length)` and get zero no matter what I send after the exe..

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", args.Length);
    }
}
```

then I run `...\setup.exe yes no maybe` and get 0 for length.  What more do I need to do?

MORE INFO:

I tried to break after setting command line arguments in the properties page and I get the following error.:

[image]

I am thinking that someone's comment about ClickOnce deployment is my problem.  How can I deploy in VS2010 to allow this?

MORE INFO:

I disabled "ClickOnce security settings" under Properties -> Security and was able to debug successfully, but when I click on Publish, it automatically turns this setting back on..  How do I prevent that?

Comment: @DJKRAZE: Not necessary. You can use any format of arguments (dashes, slashes, name it) and it will work anyway.

Comment: @Andy: Does `Console.WriteLine(args.Length)` not work too?

Comment: You're doing the right thing. Break with a debugger and check out the value of args (don't forget to set the command line arguments from the project properties page)

Comment: by the way, if you have a clickonce deployment, you can't access the command line in that way

Comment: Just to be sure, this Main() is from setup.exe, right?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yes, setup.exe is the output from my Publish in VS2010, and Main is inside `class Program {}`..  I'll update my question to include that.

Comment: Have you tried using [`Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx)?

Comment: It is about ClickOnce. See linked duplicate.

Comment: Probably you need to supply in a URL. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/429351/how-does-one-pass-command-line-argument-to-a-clickonce-application

Comment: About how to disable ClickOnce, I suggest you create a new question for that.

Comment: @HenkHolterman you are correct, it is ClickOnce, but I've read through the duplicate and the help links and can't figure out how to use `ActivationArguments.ActivationData` to get the args..  Are the args passed in to setup.exe available somehow through this class?

Comment: _When_ do you want the arguments? During deploy or later when the app starts locally? @prashanth has another link.

Comment: Later, when it is run.  I am actually deploying to a shared directory and running via command-line from another machine (using the "Online only" publish option in VS).  Everything was great until I wanted to add the command line args..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Number of command line parameters = {0}", args.Length);
            for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Arg[{0}] = [{1}]", i, args[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When executed as `ConsoleApplication1.exe a b c` will output:

```
Number of command line parameters = 3
Arg[0] = [a]
Arg[1] = [b]
Arg[2] = [c]
```

See [Command Line Parameters Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288457%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Update: this code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", args.Length);
    }
}
```

When executed as `ConsoleApplication1.exe a b c` outputs

```
3
```

Above all, make sure you're executing the correct .exe.

Comment: the only difference to what I have is you use `internal` for `class Program` and `private` for `static void Main(string[] args)`.  Would those affect my situation at all?

Comment: No, those modifiers won't affect the result; see updated example in my answer. I suggest you start a new console project and paste the above code. Also, make sure you're actually passing the parameters. I used cmd.exe and ran the generated .exe file in the command prompt.

Comment: I've found it's happening because of ClickOnce deployment.  I'm passing params to the setup.exe, not my compiled .exe...

Comment: Right, I added that hint to my answer as well.

Comment: I think the answer explains what he has to do to accept command line arguments. About how to pass them using ClickOnce, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/430536/376366) might help.

Comment: It's correct in that I was targeting the wrong .exe.  I didn't know enough about ClickOnce at all so my question has kind of spiderwebbed into a ClickOnce security/.exe targeting question.  I'm trying to research ClickOnce right now and come up with a better question, if necessary.  I'm a little new to SOF question-asking, so what should I do when my question completely changes, delete the original question?  Sorry, trying to get work done and follow SOF protocol at the same time, haha

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can do something like this in a for loop to check what the values if any of the command arguments are

```
public class CountCommandLineArgs
{
   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Number of command line parameters = {0}",
          args.Length);
       foreach(string s in args)
       {
          Console.WriteLine(s);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: When `args.Lenght == 0` then this won't Write much.

Comment: assuming he doesn't pass command line params you're correct but I am going under the assumption that he is passing params according to MSDN this is one approach 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288457%28v=vs.71%29.aspx