# Open custom file, args is always empty

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I have C# WinForm .NET 4.5 application. I set Project -> Properties -> Publish -> Options -> File Associations. This part seems to work because it sets icon that I selected and if I double click file with custom extension (in this case *.psi) it opens my application. But I am having hard time getting file name that was double clicked. Somehow my static void Main(string[] args) args are always empty. 
I use ClickOnce deployment method.

Can anyone help me with what I am missing to open custom file with my application.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if(args.Length > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(args[0]);
        }else {
          MessageBox.Show("args is empty!");
        }

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        DevExpress.Skins.SkinManager.EnableFormSkins();

        UserLookAndFeel.Default.SetSkinStyle(Properties.Settings.Default.ActiveSkinName);


        Application.Run(new MainForm(args));
    }
```

Comment: What was the 'open' command you specified when registering your file extension?

Comment: My manifest file has this line: <fileAssociation extension=".psi" description="PSISuite Project File" progid="01" defaultIcon="favicon.ico" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v1" />

Comment: Sorry,  Rufus L your link doesn't really have answer to my question.

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607632/how-to-get-command-line-from-a-clickonce-application)

> When you publish an app with ClickOnce and then launch it by double-clicking an associated file, the path to that file actually gets stored here:
>
> **AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData[0]**
>
> See MSDN's documentation for it here:
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.hosting.activationarguments.aspx
>
> Plus a tutorial on adding file associations to "Published" projects:
>
> http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mwade/archive/2008/01/30/how-to-add-file-associations-to-a-clickonce-application.aspx

Comment: Copy-pasting whole answer is generally not recommended - you could flag your question to be closed as duplicate (which is perfectly fine way to mark question as solved problem).